# Two Factor Authentication in pac4j

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, oauth, two-factor-authentication

Recently I came across [Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j) Project which provides powerful security engine fro both authentication and authorization.

To extend my security I want to implement Two Factor Authentication and Captcha validation in [Pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j), But unable to find the entry point in the same reference.

Please suggest .